# InDesign baseline grid setup

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, page-layout, grids, document-setup

I've come across many similar questions relating to similar projects on Stack Exchange Meta. Despite this, I still can't quite translate to my own project and problem.

I believe this is fundamentally a math question. I struggle desperately with math and logical thinking, so can't work out what calculations are needed or whether this is possible for my document.

I have created a z-fold document.
I calculated a layout grid using the following dimensions:

Each individual page is 99mmx210mm
I set a margin for each page to 1cm (10mm)
I want to divided the space within the margins into 9 rows and 3 columns.  I've set a gutter width between each row and column to 2mm (I wanted it to be small, as I have a lot of content to place).

[image: layout grid complete]

This is what I am left with - all good!

I then now want to set up the baseline grid to fit with this layout grid, as I will be using a fair bit of text in the design.

As my copy will be set to a point size of 10 (10pts) I set the baseline grid increment to 10 pts also, lined up within the margins.

This is what I am left with:
[image]

I believe I am struggling with logical maths equations or something. Any insight or formula explanations that would help me both with this project, and for calculating future projects, would be appreciated.

Following guidance:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, I haven't had desired effect?

Comment: You should set the grid increments according to leading / line spacing, not type size... that'll definitely help! :)

Comment: Try 12 or 13 pts increments

Comment: Oh yes I realised this at one point and set to 12pt as that will be my leading. This didn't line up either unfortunately

Comment: If your leading is 12pt, then your baseline grid should also be 12pt, not 10pt.

Comment: So I should try follow your calculations explanation and work out the whole thing again!?

Comment: Yeap, pretty much.

Comment: I'll give it a go...

I found this:
https://medium.com/@flobin/creating-a-baseline-grid-in-indesign-df0139e290ac
Is this your calculation too?

I know it's basic, but honestly this is hell to me

Comment: Looks like the exact same kind of calculation. You do need to understand these numbers to properly use grids. Or just design without a grid which is also perfectly fine if you know what you're doing. There's a book called MAKING AND BREAKING THE GRID and what it says is, once you get to understand grids, you'll also understand their limitations. There's no secret formula that you HAVE TO USE grids :)

Comment: THANK YOU! I don't think relying on my maths will prove a good move.. this whole process has put me off learning design, which is a shame as I find the visual theory etc fascinating. So maybe getting as particular as baseline grids may be an unhelpful detail. Thanks Lucian as ever!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a math problem indeed.

Not sure why do you need the horizontal so-called 'rows'. The baseline grid looks correct, but the horizontal lines don't make sense. Those have nothing to do with the baseline grid and the way text will flow into your columns.

Also, not sure you're aware you're dealing with 2 units of measurement, MM for the layout and PT for the baseline grid.

Math speaking, 1 MM equals 2.83465 PT, so if you really need that setup, try with these settings:

[image]

Numbers explained:

- 9 sets of 5 lines of 10 points = 450 points
- 8 lines of 10 points = 80 points
- total 530 points
- 530 points / 2.83465 = 186.971mm
- (210mm - 186.971mm) / 2 = 11.514mm

Comment: The rows are so I can divide the content into 9 sections as it runs down the page. This is so the design lines up across the z-fold when opened up, and is harmonious.

I know I am using two measurements. This is because I am printing the design, and much of print design deals with mms for layout and calculations. And then text size is discussed commonly using points.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Stupid I know, but could you please explain how you calculated this, and how you calculated that the margins needed to be 11.514mm for my grid to fit with the baseline?

Comment: I've also updated following your setup guide but haven't had desired outcome?

Comment: Thanks Lucian. Why do you set to top of page rather than to margins?

Comment: In addition: be aware that Indesign "engine" measurements are... picas. Meaning that if you use metric system (A4), you might encounter rounding issues. For instance, try to create a text frame snapping to the margins. It will show 186.972 mm. Try to change units to picas, it will show 44p1.999. So if you fill with text that snaps the baseline grid, the last line might not show up. Ugly isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The [Layout Grid Calculator plugin](http://layoutgridcalculator.com) for Adobe InDesign can help you.